# Haskell Stack: compilation fails when library versions change

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I've started using the [Haskell Stack](http://haskellstack.org), mostly as a vehicle to compile and run the [iHaskell kernel](https://github.com/gibiansky/IHaskell) for [jupyter](http://jupyter.org).

I am on macOS 10.13 and using [homebrew](http://brew.sh) to supply needed libraries. I try to keep these up-to-date, but this means that when running `stack install` after updating with homebrew I sometimes get error messages like

```
Configuring ihaskell-plot-0.3.0.0...
Preprocessing library ihaskell-plot-0.3.0.0...
[1 of 1] Compiling IHaskell.Display.Plot ( IHaskell/Display/Plot.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.24.2.0/build/IHaskell/Display/Plot.o )
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/Cellar/pango/1.40.13/lib'
Installing library in
/Users/jaffe/home/python/IHaskell/.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/lts-9.14/8.0.2/lib/x86_64-osx-ghc-8.0.2/ihaskell-plot-0.3.0.0-NgQdZJT4fgFyloQxui3eM
```

as homebrew has updated to a newer version of (in this case) `pango` since I most recently installed [stack](http://haskellstack.org) and therefore there are files in the global `~/.stack` directory that point to the wrong libraries. The only fix I have found is to delete all of `~/.stack` and recompile everything. (Note that the problem is indeed because of out-of-date files in the global `~/.stack`, not the local project directory).

For my current use case, where this is essentially the only thing for which I use stack, this isn't a big deal, but I can imagine that it could get to be a pain if I have many projects going.

So: Is there any easy way to force recompilation/regeneration of just the appropriate files in `~/.stack` rather than the whole directory?

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/1476) issue describe your problem?

Comment: @Alec, I think so, at least filib's description sounds the same. I admit I can't tell from the thread on GitHub whether there is any resolution/workaround.

Comment: Followup: I think for the above problem I should be doing `stack exec -- ghc-pkg unregister --force ihaskell-plot` and then `stack install`?